# Java - How to implement case-senstive username and password

Tags: java, mysql, oauth, case-sensitive

So I making this login form where the credentials (username and password) are stored in MYSQL. I want the username and password to be case sentive.

AuthDAO.java

```
public static int checkUserPass(String username, String password){
    int userId = -1;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/b440", "root", "b440");

        String q="SELECT userId FROM user WHERE username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"'";

        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);
        while(rs.next()){
            userId=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("userId"));
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();         
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DB_close();
    if(userId!=-1)
        return userId;
    return -1;
}
```

LoginServlet.java

```
else{
    int ID = checkUserPass(username, password, role);
    if(ID!=-1 ){ //User Is Legit!!
        loggedIn = "true";
        HttpSession se = request.getSession();
        se.setAttribute("user", getUserById(ID));
        se.setAttribute("loggedIn", loggedIn);
        url = "/index.jsp";
        msg = "Login Successful!";

        request.setAttribute("loggedIn", loggedIn);
        request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
    }
    else{
        msg = "Invalid Login, please check username or password";
        url = "/login.jsp";
        loggedIn = "false";
        request.setAttribute("loggedIn", loggedIn);
        request.setAttribute("msg", msg);           
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by case sensitive?

Comment: Not what you asked - but PLEASE read all about SQL injection attacks.

Comment: It means it should differentiate between capital and lower case letters. For eg: if the username and passwords are Flash and faST respectively then it shouldn't accept flash, FLASH or fast, FAST as the login credentials.

Comment: For god's sake please change to [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to fill in username and password and use a secure hashing algorihm with [salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to store passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default mysql queries are case-insensitive.

though you can use `BINARY` like this -

```
SELECT userId FROM user WHERE BINARY username='"+username+"' AND  BINARY password='"+password+"'
```

---

Or there are some other ways -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html